# How to map from a DTO with a foreign key into a hierarchy of nested objects

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm wishing to use AutoMapper in C# .NET Core to map a set of API responses which are implicitly structured by foreign keys to a set of entity objects so I can store in a DB. I'm receiving the following payload from 3 individual endpoints:.

```
public class CompanyResponse
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HeadOffice { get; set; }
}

public class FactoryResponse
{
    public int FactoryId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductResponse
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FactoryId { get; set; }
}
```

This is the nested structure I would like to hold them in:

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HeadOffice { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Factory> Factories { get; set; }
}

public class Factory
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There is a one to many relationship from Company -> Factory, and Factory -> Product respectively.

Mapping over the properties like "Name", and "HeadOffice" etc is easy, and I have created AutoMapper maps from each DTO to their corresponding object. However I do not know how to deduce the list of child objects from the Id's.

Here are the maps I have so far:

```
CreateMap<CompanyResponse, Company>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.HeadOffice, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.HeadOffice));

CreateMap<FactoryResponse, Factory>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address));

CreateMap<ProductResponse, Product>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible since AutoMapper has no knowledge of other collections when mapping one of them.

Comment: As a side note, you do not need to map properties with the same name (e.g. Name/HeadOffice) these with be mapped automaticaly

Comment: This needs to be accomplished outside of AutoMapper

Comment: You wont be able to do that inside of the mapping contenxt. Furthermore, mapping from DTO to domain objects is not recommended https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/

Comment: I believe there was confusion in my question - the models I wish to map from are acquired through a response to an external endpoint request. They are response objects which I would like to map to entity objects. I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: @ZephyrAxis what you describe is the job of LINQ, not AutoMapper. AutoMapper is meant to automate fairly straightforward mappings, not transform the structure of object graphs. Jota Toledo's link explains why AutoMapper isn't going to implement such features. So does [AutoMapper's Design Philosophy](https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy/).

Comment: @ZephyrAxis besides, given the shape of the DTOs you can just insert them to the database directly without trying to create an object graph. Those DTOs look like they are raw table rows from a many-to-many relation, or serialized DataTables. It's probably easier to just insert those rows to the database directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your response, but I'm using Entity framework - hence the models have to be mapped to entity models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have mentioned that AutoMapper has no knowledge of other collections - hence in order to solve my problem I had to create the hierarchy within the response models. I did this by adding an IEnumerable property within each parent to hold their children.

Then I looped over each of the models and added their corresponding children as follows:

```
var companyResults = await companyEndpointService.GetAllAsync();
var factoryResults = await factoryEndpointService.GetAllAsync();
var productResults = await productEndpointService.GetAllAsync();

foreach (var company in companyResults)
{
    company.Factories = factoryResults
        .Where(factory => factory.CompanyId == company.CompanyId);

    foreach (var factory in company.Factories)
    {
        factory.Products = productResults
            .Where(product => product.FactoryId == factory.FactoryId);
    }
}
```

After this heirarchy was set up, I was then able to perform a simple map as follows:

```
_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyResponse>, IEnumerable<Company>>(companyResults);
```

All the nested mapping happened automagically, and everything was good to go.